# Area code is not set in setup upgrade command installing data

Tags: magento2, module, error, setup-upgrade, command

setup upgrade command throws error while Installing data Area code is not set.
The issue is coming from webkul core module. Anybody faced similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed! I added this in installData.php

- protected $state;
- \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState in __construct params
- $this->state = $appState;

And below code in start of install() function:

```
try{
        $this->state->getAreaCode();
    }
    catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $ex) {
        $this->state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
    }
```

Comment: I face the same issue at the time of setup upgrade for the Webkul_MpShipStation module, I try the above solution but not works.